# c# Hashtable sorted by Keys

Tags: c#, sorting, hashtable, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a hashtable with keys in  alphabetic and values in numeric.
how to sort the hashtable based on keys?

```
ExchangeA, 200
ExchangeV, 100
ExchangeC, 200
```

to be like this

```
ExchangeA, 200
ExchangeC, 200
ExchangeV, 100
```

Comment: A hashtable is an inherently unordered data structure. What are you trying to do? It would be possible to create a sorted List of the key/value pairs, will this do what you want?

Comment: Several answers suggest using linq's `Enumerable.OrderBy` extension method.  It bears mention that hashtables and dictionaries can have custom equality comparers; if you are relying on this feature, you may want to use the `OrderBy` overload that accepts a custom `IComparer` instance, to provide an ordering that is compatible with the equality relation you've used to compile the hashtable or dictionary.

Comment: I would say you want to use a SortedList or a SortedDictionary

Answer (score 17):

You can use a [`SortedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) for this which will do the sorting by key for you. In your case a  `SortedDictionary<string, int>` would work:

```
SortedDictionary<string, int> dict = new SortedDictionary<string, int>();
dict.Add("Exchange C", 200);
dict.Add("Exchange A", 200);
dict.Add("Exchange V", 100);

foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

Output:

```
Key = Exchange A, Value = 200
Key = Exchange C, Value = 200
Key = Exchange V, Value = 100
```

Comment: It is worth noting that `SortedDictionary` is implemented internally by a binary search tree, and has `O(lg n)` retrieval rather than the expected `O(1)` retrieval of a hash table. Depending on the OP's needs, he may want this or he may want to do an OrderBy as in other answers

Comment: Yes - that is a great point to make - using a `SortedDictionary` is only worthwhile if retrieving by key in order has to be done often / always and the key lookup time is not critical (`O(lg n)` is still great, but certainly worse than `O(1)`)

Comment: @GabeMoothart there is another advantage of `SortedDictionary<,>`: It doesn't use arrays, while `Dictionary<,>` does.  If you have huge numbers of objects and you get into problems with large object heap fragmentation, `SortedDictionary<,>` is a quick solution to keep your data off the large object heap.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way I found to "sort" hashtable is:

```
var hash = new Hashtable();
var orderedKeys = hash.Keys.Cast<string>().OrderBy(c => c); // supposing you're using string keys
var allKvp = from x in orderedKeys select new{ key = x, value = hash[x] };
```

However, Im not ordering the original hashtable, only reading its values in an ordered way.

As in other replies, if you need to store your data is sorted way, the best is to use SortedDictionary

Answer (score 2):

Because of the nature of hash tables, you cannot sort them on the key in place: they organize their keys in buckets based on their hash code, a value outside of hash table's control. However, you can read key-value pairs in whatever order that you like. Here is how you can do it using LINQ:

```
IDictionary<string, int> d = ...; // your hash table
var ordered = d.OrderBy(p => p.Key).ToList();
foreach (var p in ordered) {
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0} Value: {1}", p.Key, p.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a list instead of a hash (or convert your hash to a dictionary), and do this:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var l = dictionary.Keys.ToList();
l.Sort();
foreach (var key in l)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dictionary[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq is easy (`using System.Linq`):

```
var sortedList = (from kv in MyDictionary select kv order by kv.Key).ToList<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
```

That returns a list of `KeyValuePair<string, int>`.

Answer (score 0):

I used a list to store keys of Hashtable and sorted it and then dislayed Hashtable using this sorted list. Here is my code:

> ```
>         List<string> lst = new List<string>();
>         foreach (var key2 in ht.Keys)
>         {
>             lst.Add(key2.ToString());
>         }
>         lst.Sort();
>         foreach (var item in lst)
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1}", item, ht[item.ToString()]));
>         }
> ```