# Sorting Hashtable on key Basis?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, hashtable

How do i sort hashtable  on key basis in c#.
Eg.

```
Hastable hst  = new Hashtable ();
hst.Add("Key1","keyValue");
hst.Add("Key2","keyValue");
hst.Add("Key3","keyValue");
```

Comment: The notion of *sorting* hardly makes any sense for a hashtable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# Hashtable sorted by Keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280054/c-sharp-hashtable-sorted-by-keys)

Answer (score 3):

If you need a sorted strongly typed hashtable, you can use [`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx)

```
var hst  = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
hst.Add("Key1","keyValue");
hst.Add("Key2","keyValue");
hst.Add("Key3","keyValue");
```

If you want to stick to a hashtable:

```
IEnumerable<DictionaryEntry> sortedEntries = hst.OrderBy(entry => entry.Key);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this question, the answer there are great.
[Is it possible to sort a HashTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675759/is-it-possible-to-sort-a-hashtable)

Hashtables work by mapping keys to values. Implicit in this mapping is the concept that the keys aren't sorted or stored in any particular order.
However, you could take a look at `SortedDictionary<K,V>.`

Another option is to construct the hash table as you're already doing, and then simply construct a sorted set from the keys. You can iterate through that sorted key set, fetching the corresponding value from the hash table as needed.