# Sort a list according to another list

Tags: c#

I have a `list1` like this :

```
{A,B,C,D,E,F}
```

I have another `list2` that `list2` count is equal with `list1` count (6=6) :

```
{50,100,14,57,48,94}
```

I want sort `list1` according to `list2`, that `list2` to be sorted ascending.

```
{14,48,50,57,94,100}
```

as a result :

```
{C,E,A,D,F,B}
```

I used the following code. But the result is not sorted

```
list1= list1.OrderBy(d => list2.IndexOf(d)).ToList();
```

Comment: I read this twice and I still have no idea what you are asking.  Maybe I have missed something...

Comment: How do the elements in your two lists rely on each other?

Comment: @HimBromBeereIn another function, they are assigned and rely on each other

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280054/c-sharp-hashtable-sorted-by-keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int index = 0;
list1 = list1.OrderBy(d => list2[index++]).ToList();
```

It should produce the expected result given the following two lists:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
List<int> list2 = new List<int> { 50, 100, 14, 57, 48, 94 };
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not use a sorted dictionary?

```
var list1 = new List<int> { 50, 100, 14, 57, 48, 94 }
var list2 = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
var dict = new SortedDictionary<int, string>();

for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
{
   dict.Add(list1[i], list2[i]);
}
```

You'll now be able to access the values in the correct order.

Comment: Comparable to my solution, but in a single step. Definitly better

Comment: @mm8 The OP isn't simply sorting a list, they're sorting it based on other criteria.Plus, this allows them to access the data based on an index later.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this directly if you use an array instead of a list:

```
string[] list1 = 
{
    "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"
};

int[] list2 = 
{
    50, 100, 14, 57, 48, 94
};

Array.Sort(list2, list1);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list1)); // C, E, A, D, F, B
```

The [`Array.Sort(Array keys, Array items)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85y6y2d3(v=vs.110).aspx) method is provided for this exact purpose.

> Sorts a pair of one-dimensional Array objects (one contains the keys and the other contains the corresponding items) based on the keys in the first Array using the IComparable implementation of each key.

Sadly, there is no equivalent for `List<T>`.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Zip__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__System_Func___0___1___2__) to combine them, then `OrderBy` to order

Applies a specified function to the corresponding elements of two sequences, producing a sequence of the results.

```
var first = new List<char>() { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };

var second = new List<double>() { 50, 100, 14, 57, 48, 94 };

var results = first.Zip(second, (f, s) => (first: f, second: s))
                   .OrderBy(x => x.second)
                   .Select(x => x.first);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", results ));
```

**Output**

```
C, E, A, D, F, B
```

Comment: It worth saying that for arrays, there is a built-in method to solve this specific problem: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.8#System_Array_Sort_System_Array_System_Array_

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
docs = docs.OrderBy(d => docsIds.IndexOf(d.Id)).ToList();
```

should give the expected result.