# Sorting list according to another list

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a`List<XYZ>`, let's call it`oListXYZ`.

`{{3,2,1},{6,5,4},{9,8,7}}`

and a`List<double>`we'll call`oListD`.

`{9,2,5}`

Both lists are related, i.e`oListD[i]`corresponds to`oListXYZ[i]`.I need to sort the`XYZ`values in`oListXYZ`according to their corresponding`double`values in`oListD`, like so:

`{2,5,9}`
`{{6,5,4},{9,8,7},{3,2,1}}`

Using`oListD.Sort`gives the desired order, but i need a way to sort`oListXYZ`following said order.

I have tried with LINQ or the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50702846/sort-a-list-according-to-another-list), but haven't found the desired results yet.

Comment: I don't understand the question @_@.

Comment: what is their 'corresponding double value'? I dont think you've given enough info here for us to help

Comment: Can you post some tests case (i.e. a list of inputs/outputs)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Zip__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__System_Func___0___1___2__) to combine them, then `OrderBy` to order

> Applies a specified function to the corresponding elements of two
>   sequences, producing a sequence of the results.

```
var list = new List<(int, int, int)>(){(3, 2, 1),(6, 5, 4),(9, 8, 7)};

var doubles = new List<double>(){9,2,5};

var results = list.Zip(doubles, (tuple, d) => (t: tuple, d: d))
                  .OrderBy(x => x.d)
                  .Select(x => x.t);

foreach (var result in results)
   Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Output**

```
(6, 5, 4)
(9, 8, 7)
(3, 2, 1)
```

Comment: Your answer is superb - it's easily better than the ones in the duplicate question - I'd suggest you go and post yours there too (with a bit of tweaking).

Comment: Exactly the kind of solution i was looking for. Simple and to the point. Thank you.