# Does OrderBy calls guarantee to call the keySelector only once per element?

Tags: c#, linq

In [his (accepted) response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50702899/361177) about synchronized sorting, [mm8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7252182/mm8) provided this piece of code:

```
int index = 0;
list1 = list1.OrderBy(d => list2[index++]).ToList();
```

The code heavily relies on the fact that `OrderBy` will call the provided `keySelector`:

- with the argument in the original sequence order
- only once per element

Even if [current implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,2648) of `OrderBy` actually works like so, is there any guarantee about it?

I didn't find any clues of it in [the `OrderBy` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8). Neither in the LINQ guideline.

**Edit**: Obviously changing the behavior is a breaking change for code that rely on it (like mm8 code). My question is more about: does this behavior was guaranteed to be immutable when `OrderBy` was provided, or it's now a *fait accompli*?.

Comment: Not sure what your question is here? `is there any guarantee about it?`

Comment: Personally, I'm comfortable with the fact that the selector will be called once per element: there's a lot of code which does things like `.OrderBy(x => new Guid())` which would break if this wasn't preserved, and .NET hates breaking backwards compatibility. I'm not so confident with the key selector being called *in order*, but I don't see a reason this would change necessarily

Comment: `is there any guarantee about it?`. Yep that is my question. Does `OrderBy` will forever and ever call the `keySelector` with the argument in the original sequence order and only once per element. Obviously changing the behavior is a breaking change for code that rely on it (example already provided), and it's a `fait accompli`  that `OrderBy` works like so. My question is more about: does this behavior was guaranteed to be immutable when OrderBy was provided.

Comment: Another thing to consider is the OrderBy works on an IEnumerable, so it will call the key selector once for each item on every iteration. The 'guarantee' of it calling it once in you're example is due to the fact that you call ToList immediately after. While it doesn't answer your question fully, it might shed some light on why the behavior is not documented and guaranteed... because there is no guarantee what you will do with the resulting IEnumerable from the OrderBy function.. if you iterate more than once you're key function will be called multiple times per item

Comment: You're asking the wrong community. We can't guarantee anything.

Comment: @Orace have you had a chance to look at the answers below?

Comment: @Joel yes I did. My conclusion is that the Linq documentation lacks of precision. The precise behavior of 'OrderBy' and other methods is neither ensured nor ''not guaranteed". In your response you says that the behavior is not guaranteed but this is not clearly stated in the documentation.

Comment: @Orace no, and that is because the documentation is constantly changing. So the answer to your question (*and in my answer*) is No, you cannot guarantee that it wont change (things have changed before, see the link of historic examples i provided).

Answer (score 1):

According to [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,2650) its called once. But it can be changed in future - no guarantee:

```
internal override void ComputeKeys(TElement[] elements, int count) 
{
    keys = new TKey[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) keys[i] = keySelector(elements[i]);
    if (next != null) next.ComputeKeys(elements, count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the inputs in the linked answer a new example could be constructed.

```
var list1 = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
var list2 = new List<int> { 90, 50, 40 };
```

Running

```
int index = 0;
list1 = list1.OrderBy(d => list2[index++]).ToList();
```

Will be called **once per element** and the output will look like this:

> list1 = {"C","B","A"}
>
> list2 = {90,50,40}

Regarding *any guarantees that this behaviour won't change?*:

No, there's no guarantee. Read [Jon Skeets Article on C# history of things that have broken / changed behaviour between versions](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/03/02/backward-compatibility-pain/) in the past.